# ActionMailer ArgumentError - SMTP-AUTH requested but missing secret phrase

Tags: smtp, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer, yandex

I am using Yandex Connect (SMTP) as a method to send emails from my Rails 5 JSON API app.

Here's the setup:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.yandex.com',
    port:                 25,
    domain:               ENV['MAIL_DOMAIN'],
    user_name:            ENV['MAIL_USER'],
    password:             ENV['MAIL_PASSWORD'],
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
end
```

I also have `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ENV['MAIL_DOMAIN'] }` set in my `application.rb`

On heroku with the right credentials it works just fine. But when I try to run the same config localy and send an email, I get `ArgumentError - SMTP-AUTH requested but missing secret phrase`.

What could be wrong

Answer (score 2):

1) Make sure the environment variables are really there, e.g. `bundle exec rails console`, `puts ENV.inspect`

2) Make sure the credentials are correct

3) Restart your development server after you've modified your environment. This includes `spring stop`.

Comment: ENV is correct. still the same error. Even if I put the credentials directly to the config

Comment: When changing env variables, run `spring stop`